# Codeception SF4 service already initialized

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, codeception

Every time I launch my API suite I have the following error on the first test :

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException] The "doctrine.orm.client_entity_manager" service is already initialized, you cannot replace it.

The other tests are running well and if I launch my tests again the error disappears. But if I clear my cache or wait for a long time the error will occur again.

This is my API suite config :

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\SymfonyHelper:
            app_path: src
            environment: test
            em_service: doctrine.orm.client_entity_manager
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: \Helper\SymfonyHelper
            cleanup: true
        - REST:
            depends: \Helper\SymfonyHelper
            part: Json
            url: 'http://localhost/api'
        - \Helper\Api
        - Asserts
```

Thanks for help.

Edit :

This is the helper source :

`namespace Helper;`

use Codeception\Module\Symfony;

class SymfonyHelper extends Symfony
{
    /**
     * Check that an email is sent or count number of emails sent.
     *
     * @param int|null $nbEmail
     */
    public function seeEmailIsSent(?int $nbEmail = null)
    {
        $profile = $this->getProfile();
        if (!$profile) {
            $this->fail('Emails can\'t be tested without Profiler');
        }
        if (!$profile->hasCollector('swiftmailer')) {
            $this->fail('Emails can\'t be tested without SwiftMailer connector');
        }

```
    if (is_null($nbEmail)) {
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $profile->getCollector('swiftmailer')->getMessageCount());
    } else {
        $this->assertEquals($nbEmail, $profile->getCollector('swiftmailer')->getMessageCount());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using your own SymfonyHelper instead of Symfony module? Please provide the source.

Comment: I'm using my own module because i have a custom method for symfony emails, but i have the exact same error when using default module. I have added the helper source.

Comment: Any luck with this one? I'm seeing the same. The first test run after clearing the cache always fails with this error, following run is fine. Warming the cache has no effect.